# How to get items that were effective within a date range in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a table of items made in entity and I need with the query.

Each item has two properties: **Id** and **EffectiveDate**

I need a list of all the items that were effective within a date range.

This is what I have so far:

```
var monthStart = new DateTime(2019, 10, 1);
var monthEnd = new DateTime(2019, 10, 31);

var items = dbContext.Items
     .OrderByDescending(a => a.EffectiveDate)
     .where(m => m.EffectiveDate <= monthEnd && m.EffectiveDate > monthStart)
```

This gets all the correct items except one. It needs to get all the items with effective dates inside the period *and the last one before the start date*.
Right now it gets all the items with effective dates inside the period.

Is there  a way to do this in a single query?

For eample
we had items with these effective dates (DD/MM/YYYY):

1. 05/05/2000
2. 07/01/2005
3. 08/07/2019
4. 12/07/2019
5. 15/07/2019
6. 15/08/2019

And I wanted items that were effective between **01/07/2019** and **31/07/2019** the result would be:

1. 07/01/2005
2. 08/07/2019
3. 12/07/2019
4. 15/07/2019

Comment: Can you provide an example input list and desired result?

Comment: I've now added an example input and output

Comment: check using the debugger the `time` component of your dates (a.EffectiveDate)

Comment: What do you mean @JohnB

Comment: the `monthStart` newed up will have a time of "00:00:00", but what if your comparison date eg e.EffectiveDate has some time that's different?  the where expression will not give desired results...

Comment: In my use case I'm not worried about time. All dates have a time of "00:00:00", and the current code is behaving exactly as expected.

Comment: How could be **07/01/2005**  output as you mentioned that you want result between **01/07/2019 and 31/07/2019** Date range?

Comment: I can't think of a way to handle this in a single expression. I would keep your current expression, then use a sorted version of your input list to grab index corresponding to `your first result -1`. You'd most likely need to do some checking here though, to make sure you're within bounds.

Comment: becuase it needs all the ones inbetween those dates **plus one more**.

Comment: Yeah I sadly think you're right @itypewithmyhands, my actual usecase if different to this example, and it would be ideal if I could do this in a single query but it may be not possible.

Comment: It would help if you could define what you mean by `plus one more`. Is it any one? Or the last one before the start date? Or the first one after the start date? Or any random one?

Comment: Yeah the last one before the start date. I'll reword that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could concatenate your list with another subquery like this:

```
var monthStart = new DateTime(2019, 10, 1);
var monthEnd = new DateTime(2019, 10, 31);

var items = dbContext.Items
     .OrderByDescending(a => a.EffectiveDate)
     .Where(m => m.EffectiveDate <= monthEnd && m.EffectiveDate > monthStart)
     .Concat(dbContext.Items.Where(d => d.EffectiveDate < monthStart).TakeLast(1))
```